# ImageView Not Showing Image which taken from Android Media/Gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

Image view Not showing Image from gallery.Large/small image both are not working.

```
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 0;

public void GalleryAction(View v){

        Intent galleryintent=new Intent();
        galleryintent.setType("image/*");
        galleryintent.setAction("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
        startActivityForResult(galleryintent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }

Uri resultFile;
int width;
int height;
Bitmap bm,bmtamp;
String pathString ;
Matrix matrixImage1;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(requestCode==RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE){
       try{

            this.resultFile = data.getData();
            String[] arrayOfString = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor localCursor = getContentResolver().query(SavingFrameActivity.outputFileUri, arrayOfString, null, null, null);

            localCursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = localCursor.getColumnIndex(arrayOfString[0]);
            this.pathString = localCursor.getString(columnIndex);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.photoImage, options);
            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            String imageType = options.outMimeType;

           this.imgview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoImage);
           this.width=this.imgview.getWidth();
           this.height=this.imgview.getHeight();
this.bm=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.photoImage, 100, 100);
//this.bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(this.pathString, this.imgview);
      this.imgview.setOnTouchListener(new MyonTouchListener());

      if (this.bm != null)
      {
        this.imgview.setImageBitmap(this.bm);
        this.matrixImage1 = new Matrix();
        this.imgview.setImageMatrix(this.matrixImage1);
      }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }


    }
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


  public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options paramOptions, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
    {
      int i = paramOptions.outHeight;
      int j = paramOptions.outWidth;
      int k = 1;
      int n;
      if ((i > paramInt2) || (j > paramInt1))
      {
        int m = Math.round(i / paramInt2);
        n = Math.round(j / paramInt1);
        if (m < n)
          k = m;
      }
      else
      {
        return k;
      }
      return n;
    }
```

LogCat Report:

```
02-20 15:06:12.799: W/System.err(23706): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1094)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:354)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at com.krushnanlabs.savingframe.SavingFrameActivity.onActivityResult(SavingFrameActivity.java:108)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
02-20 15:06:12.815: W/System.err(23706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: SavingFrameActivity.java:108 what is here in this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this working code which I used fro same requirement

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Anil ,Your code working.But I used same code which i written above by calling decodeSampledBitmapFromResourcefrom from other class.It's working now.